# Disabling color on font awesome icon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I just added a href tag to my font awesome icon, which alters its color like so:

[image]

Is there a way to remove this link color?

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
```

Comment: Seems like you know CSS is involved, so what have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I tried to remove the decoration before, because I didn't know you can't do that with font awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS:

```
.fa-facebook {
    color: black; /* or any other color */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't "remove" the color, but you can change the color to something else.

Simply use CSS with a class

```
a.black{color: #000 !important}
```

Or on all `a`tags

```
a{color: #000 !important}
```

Or directly on the tag

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" style="color: #000 !important"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
```

I'm adding the important tag, to ensure it stays black when being clicked or active.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the color for all .fa icons inside anchor tags

```css
a .fa {
    color: black;
}
```

#### Demo in Stack Snippets

```css
a .fa {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="https://www.w3schools.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
```